# PHP Accessing Child's protected value from parent

Tags: php, oop

I have this code that i want to do method abstraction in parent and child will define the property

```
class SuperClass{
    static protected $message = "This is the parent";

    public static function showMessage(){
        echo self::$message."<br/>";
    }
}

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
    static protected $message = "This is the first child";

}

class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
    static protected $message = "This is the second child";
}

SuperClass::showMessage();
SubClass1::showMessage();
SubClass2::showMessage();
```

I would expect to see

```
This is the parent
This is the first child
This is the second child
```

But what i got is

```
This is the parent
This is the parent
This is the parent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very classical use-case of [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). 
Simply replace keyword "self" in the parent class by "static"

```
class SuperClass{
    static protected $message = "This is the parent";

    public static function showMessage(){
        echo static::$message."<br/>";
    }
}
```

This will work for php 5.3+